# How to extend audio file into a new duration - adding silent to beginning and ending of the audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, audio-processing

I have a wav file named as `a.wav`.

Let's say it is `9.432` seconds.

I want to extend it to `13.321` seconds.

So I need to add silence to both beginning and end of video to `1.945` seconds.

The reason is I am working on a TTS application and I want to generate entire speech from a given subtitle srt or vtt file

So how can I do this perhaps with ffmpeg?

What command should I run?

Comment: `-af adelay=delays=1945:all=1,apad=pad_dur=1.945`